# What files Gradle packs into a jar archive?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, source-sets

What expression (in `build.gradle` file) evaluates to list of files that are packed into a jar archive by default (without adjusting "jar" task?

I can't easily spot it in sources of [`org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/platform-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/jvm/tasks/Jar.java) and [`org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.java).

This question is motivated by using of a custom sourceSet files of which are not added to jar archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the Java Plugin that adds the `jar` task and configures it. You can see this in the source code of the `org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaPlugin` class:

```java
private TaskProvider<Jar> registerJarTaskFor(Project project, JavaPluginConvention pluginConvention) {
    return project.getTasks().register(JAR_TASK_NAME, Jar.class, jar -> {
        jar.setDescription("Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.");
        jar.setGroup(BasePlugin.BUILD_GROUP);
        jar.from(mainSourceSetOf(pluginConvention).getOutput());
    });
}
```

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/e343cfe2b37317a3de119da2809887f76042fe0d/subprojects/plugins/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPlugin.java#L315-L321